VBScript: The system cannot find the file specified
I am trying to have a script open Active Directory, but for some reason, the script refuses to locate the file. I have tried countless other exe/msc files in place of it that have worked without issue, but dsa.msc simply won't work.
<script language="VBScript">
Sub LAUNCH_WEBSITE (choice)
    Dim objShell, webPage
    Set objShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    If (choice = 1) Then
        webPage = "https://"
    ElseIf (choice = 2) Then
        webPage = "https://"
    ElseIf (choice = 3) Then
        objShell.Run "C:\Windows\System32\dsa.msc", 1, False
    End If
    objShell.Run webPage
End Sub
</script>

I have also tried """C:\Windows\System32\dsa.msc""" but have received the same error.
Edit: I should also specify that this script is being run as part of an html application. I have tested a regular .vbs file and was able to launch active directory without issue.
Set objShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "dsa.msc", 1, False

But even linking that in the HTA would say that dsa.msc could not be located.

Have you tried C:\Windows\SysNative\dsa.msc? If for some reason you are using the 32-bit version of mshta.exe and dsa.msc exists only in the 64-bit system directory, it may not be found. If that's not it, check with Process Monitor what file access attempts happen. Configure the filter as Path ends with dsa.msc for example.

Last resort would be C:\Windows\SysNative\cmd.exe /c dsa.msc

HTA scripts run in 32 bit mode by default. VBS scripts run in 64 bit mode by default. Try running your HTA in 64 bit mode by running mshta.exe from System32 and providing the full path to your HTA on the command line. For example C:\windows\system32\mshta "C:\Test\Test.hta"

Does this answer your question? ACE OLEDB provider in vbscript in HTML application (hta) to read an excel says provider not installed, vbs is working but hta is not working
